# ggplot: percentage counts line graph for factor groups on a scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

Say I want to plot percentages of "yes" answers to a question, across different age groups in ggplot.  These age groups are obviously factors, but I want them to be shown in a scale-like fashion, so want to use a line graph.

Here's some data:

```
mydata <- data.frame(
    age_group = c("young", "middle", "old"),
    question = sample(c("yes", "no"), 99, replace = TRUE))
mydata$age_group = factor(mydata$age_group,levels(mydata$age_group)[c(3, 1, 2)])  
mydata$question = factor(mydata$question,levels(mydata$question)[c(2,1)])
```

So far, I have been using this code to generate a stacked barplot:

```
 ggplot(mydata, aes(age_group, fill = question)) +  geom_bar(position = "fill")
```

How could I change this into a line graph, with just the frequency counts of the "yes" answers?  Mark in the answers suggests a workaround which produces the right output:
[image]

But I hoping there was a way to do this automatically in one line of code, rather than creating this summary table first.

Comment: I don't understand. You just want a line graph which essentially will connect the tops of the pink bars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the percentages of "yes" for each category, I suggest changing your data to the following:

```
  question age_group value   percent
1      yes     young    14 0.4242424
3      yes    middle    17 0.5151515
5      yes       old    20 0.6060606
```

Using this code to summarize the data:

```
library(reshape)
mydata.summary = melt(xtabs(~question+age_group,data=mydata))
mydata.summary2 = mydata.summary[mydata.summary$question=="yes",]
mydata.summary2$percent <- mydata.summary2$value/melt(xtabs(~age_group,data=mydata))$value
ggplot(mydata.summary2, aes(age_group,percent, group = question, colour=question)) + geom_line()
```

Comment: This works if you add `) + geom_line()` which I assume got cut off your answer.  I'd been kind of doing it this way anyway as a workaround, but it's a bit of a pain.  I just wondered if there was a more efficient way.

Answer (score 5):

If I understood correctly, this does what you want:

```
ggplot(mydata) + 
  stat_bin(aes(x=age_group, color=question, group=question), geom="line")
```

[image]

Note this doesn't look exactly the same as yours in terms of yes/no because you didn't set a seed for the random numbers.

Comment: Almost, but I want the percentage, not the absolute counts.

Comment: @Danielle, you can change `geom=area` and `color=question` to `fill=question`, add `position=fill`, which will work but will be an area chart instead of a line chart.  Unfortunately I don't know how to both stack and fill lines.